# Prevent python flooding server with task from for loop

Tags: python, celery

I have a task that runs every night that updates users from a external system. How can I prevent my server flooding the external system with request?

My code:

```
@task()
def update_users():

    #Get all users
    users = User.objects.all()

    for userobject in users:
        #send to update task:            
        update_user.apply_async(args=[userobject.username,], countdown=15)
```

Is there any way to "slow down" the forloop, or is it possible to make celery not executing a task, if there is already a task running?

Comment: You can simply put a `sleep(0.1)` or whatever time, depending on the number of users you have. I don't know if there is a callback for executed tasks…

Comment: You could have a worker with a concurrency of 1.

Comment: You could also set a rate limit on the task

Comment: @Garreth, feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to specify what exactly you mean with "flooding" the service. Is it the fact that many requests end up being fired *concurrently* to one server? If that is the case, a common pattern really is to apply a *pool* of workers, with a fixed size **N**. Using this approach, there is a guarantee that your service is queried with *at most* N requests concurrently. That is, at any point in time, there will be no more than N outstanding requests. This effectively throttles your request rate.

You can then play with N and do some benchmarking and see which number is reasonable in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lock on your task, forcing it to execute only once at a time for the whole pool of workers. You can check [this celery recipe](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time).

Putting a time.sleep at won't help you because there's a chance that those tasks will execute at the same time, say if there is some delay on the queue.

Answer (score -1):

1You could use time.sleep to delay your task

```
import time

@task()
def update_users():

#Get all users
users = User.objects.all()

for userobject in users:
    #send to update task:            
    update_user.apply_async(args=[userobject.username,], countdown=15)
    time.sleep(1)
```

this will delay the for loop for 1 second